# Use of references in c++

Tags: c++, reference, stack, constants

I am trying to wrap my head around the use of references. By now I have understood that references need to be constant and they are like alias to a variable. However while writing a code for the stack, when I passed value by reference to the push function. I had to include "const" keyword. I need to know why is that necessary.

In short why does THIS works

```
class stack
{
public:
    void push(const int &x);
};

void stack::push(const int &x)
{
    // some code for push
}

 int main()
 {
    stack y;
    y.push(12);
    return 0;
 }
```

But THIS does not?

```
class stack
{
public:
    void push(int &x);
};

 void stack::push(int &x)
 {
     // some code for push
 }

int main()
{
    stack y;
    y.push(12);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make sense to use a reference for push() - just copy the int.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use

```
int main()
{
    stack y;
    int X = 12;
    y.push(X);
    return 0;
}
```

you will see it works EVEN IF YOU REMOVE THE "const". It's because 12 is constant, but X is not a constant!

In other words:

- if you use `void push(const int &x);` --- you can use const OR non-const values!
- if you use `void push(int &x);` --- you can use ONLY non-const values!

The basic rule is:

- My function doesn't need to change the value of parameters: use `void push(const int &x);`
- My function needs to change the value of parameters: use `void push(int &x);` [notice here that if you are planning to change the value of your parameter, of course it can't be a constant 12, but some variable with value 12, that's the difference!]

Comment: Thank you that makes sense.Also, then does this infer that const keyword in arguments doesn't have anything to do with value(the element aliased not the data of element) of reference?

Comment: it just means that that variable can't be changed! just like in code... in code `const int X = 12` exists... X is created as const! as paramater `void function(const int &X)` X is also created as a const IF you use `function(12)`... but in the same time it can be used as an ALIAS to other variables, once `const int &X = Y` is also valid! it optimizes you to make any unnecessary copy!

Answer (score 0):

You call the push method using rvalue (literal 12). In C++ rvalue can be called using only const reference parameters, or in C++11 using the so called rvalue reference (&&).